# Check if times are equal in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I would like to check if the two time variables I have are equal .
Is there a way I can do it ?

```
DECLARE @NotificationTime DateTime;
DECLARE @CurrentTime DateTime;

SET @Notification = xxx

SET @CurrentTime = yyy
```

I want to see if

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, @Duration, @NotificationTime))
```

is equal to

CurrentTime & Date which is

```
GETDATE();
```

I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing like this:-

```
where 
  datediff(minute,DATEADD(MINUTE, @Duration, @NotificationTime),GETDATE()) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` at whatever increment you want, probably minutes or seconds:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(MINUTE, @Duration, @NotificationTime),GETDATE()) = 0
```